Variable coefficient differential equation
I am absolutely not familiar with differential equations. However, I am facing the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
a(x)y^{\prime}(x)+b(x)y(x)=c(x)\sqrt{1-d(x)y^{2}(x)}
\end{equation}
or written differently
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}(x) = p(x)y(x)+q(x)\sqrt{1-d(x)y^{2}(x)}
\end{equation}
I checked Zwillinger's handbook on differential equations and Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations by Andrei Polyanin and Valentin Zaitsev in the hope to find differential equations having a similar form. However, I could not find anything similar.
I tried to solve this equation using MATLAB using the following code:
syms x p(x) q(x) d(x) y(x)
part1 = q(x)*sqrt(1-d(x)*(y(x)*y(x)));
part2 = p(x)*y(x);
ode = (diff(y,x) == part1 + part2)
ySol(x) = dsolve(ode)

however, this did not result in a solution. I do not know how to proceed. Can you help me making the next steps or pointing me even to the solution? Thank you very much.
EDIT:
Is it of any help if the differential equation is in one of the following forms?
\begin{align}
y^{\prime}(x) &= f(x)y(x)+g(x)\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}\\
y^{\prime}(x) &= g(x)\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}y(x)+\sqrt{y^{2}(x)+1}\right)
\end{align}

Should that first "+" be an "="?

thanks for pointing out the typo
